# Tesseract for logos and Fonts

Tags: tesseract, opencv, python

There are some logos for which OCR needs to be run . Logos generally have different fonts. A sample is below. When tesseract was run with all possible psm values RITZ is not getting detected. Also tried converting to black and white using `cv2.threshold(grayImage, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`  still the R is not getting detected. Can someone tell what technique to be done for these strange fonts.  ( I am using python)

[image: RITZ logo]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with tessaract it cant detect complex or handwritten characters. We can use tesseract for simple printed character detection. For complex or handwritten you can try CNN or KNN aalgorithm trained under dataset.(chars74k, A-Z Handwritting)